# Disable output escaping for spring ws

Tags: java, web-services, soap, escaping, spring-ws

I have a bit of a problem with `spring-ws` `WebserviceTemplate`

I've created a WebserviceMessage like this

```
public WebServiceMessage createWebServiceMessage(String innerEnvelope)
    {
        SOAPMessage soapMsg=null;
        MessageFactory factory;
        try
        {
            factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

            soapMsg = factory.createMessage();
            SOAPPart part = soapMsg.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = part.getEnvelope();
            SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

            QName ejbName = new QName(EJB_VALUE,"lustraciaOsoby",EJB_PREFIX);
            SOAPElement ejbElement =body.addBodyElement(ejbName);
            ejbElement.addNamespaceDeclaration(SOAP_ENV_PREFIX, SOAP_ENV_VALUE);
            ejbElement.setAttribute("soapenv:encodingStyle", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");

            QName transName=new QName(TRANS_ELEMENT);
            SOAPElement transElement = ejbElement.addChildElement(transName);
            transElement.addNamespaceDeclaration(XSI_PREFIX, XSI_VALUE);
            transElement.addNamespaceDeclaration(XSD_PREFIX, XSD_VALUE);
            transElement.setAttribute("xsi:type", "xsd:string");

            transElement.addTextNode(innerEnvelope);

            soapMsg.saveChanges();

        } catch (SOAPException e)
        {
            LOGGER.debug("Error while creating message",e);
        }

        return (WebServiceMessage)new SaajSoapMessage(soapMsg);
    }
```

which result in XML that is looking like this(this is 100% valid request for this web service, with usage of standard `HttpConnection` it was returning valid response)

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ejb:lustraciaOsoby xmlns:ejb="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<transXmlEnc xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">
&lt;TransEnv xmlns=&quot;http://schemas.mvsr.sk/clk/clk2/lustracia_osoby_in_transxml.xsd&quot; 
xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; 
cPageSize=&quot;50&quot; cRecNoFrom=&quot;0&quot;&gt;
&lt;LOI&gt;&lt;SI&gt;2,3,5,8,19&lt;/SI&gt;&lt;PR&gt;Mrkvi&#269;ka&lt;/PR&gt;&lt;PR_PARTIAL&gt;false&lt;/PR_PARTIAL&gt;&lt;PR_FUZZY&gt;false&lt;/PR_FUZZY&gt;&lt;ME&gt;J&#225;n&lt;/ME&gt;&lt;ME_PARTIAL&gt;false&lt;/ME_PARTIAL&gt;&lt;ME_FUZZY&gt;false&lt;/ME_FUZZY&gt;&lt;LV_ANYNAME&gt;false&lt;/LV_ANYNAME&gt;
&lt;/LOI&gt;&lt;/TransEnv&gt;
</transXmlEnc>
</ejb:lustraciaOsoby>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Just for info, that escaped part is like soap in soap, which is parsed on server side.

The problem is, when I execute this with `sendSourceAndReceiveToResult`, the final `SOAP` that is sent is in this form

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ejb:lustraciaOsoby 
xmlns:ejb="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<transXmlEnc xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">
&amp;lt;TransEnv xmlns=&amp;quot;http://schemas.mvsr.sk/clk/clk2/lustracia_osoby_in_transxml.xsd&amp;quot; xmlns:xsi=&amp;quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&amp;quot; cPageSize=&amp;quot;50&amp;quot; cRecNoFrom=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;LOI&amp;gt;&amp;lt;SI&amp;gt;2,3,5,8,19&amp;lt;/SI&amp;gt;&amp;lt;PR&amp;gt;Mrkvi&amp;#269;ka&amp;lt;/PR&amp;gt;&amp;lt;PR_PARTIAL&amp;gt;false&amp;lt;/PR_PARTIAL&amp;gt;&amp;lt;PR_FUZZY&amp;gt;false&amp;lt;/PR_FUZZY&amp;gt;&amp;lt;ME&amp;gt;J&amp;#225;n&amp;lt;/ME&amp;gt;&amp;lt;ME_PARTIAL&amp;gt;false&amp;lt;/ME_PARTIAL&amp;gt;&amp;lt;ME_FUZZY&amp;gt;false&amp;lt;/ME_FUZZY&amp;gt;&amp;lt;LV_ANYNAME&amp;gt;false&amp;lt;/LV_ANYNAME&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/LOI&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/TransEnv&amp;gt;
</transXmlEnc>
</ejb:lustraciaOsoby>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Its pretty hard to spot the difference, but the trick is that all `&` are replaced with `&amp` which is a problem, because the parser on the server side can't parse it due to `Reference is not allowed in prologue` error. Without this weird escape, the request works just fine.

So my question is, is there any way to disable this additional escaping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i was able to resolve this. The problem was that input that was coming to `transElement.addTextNode(innerEnvelope);` was already escaped by `StringEscapeUtils` and apache tried to escape it again ,what cause the reescapting of `&` to `&amp`